# How to update table using Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Can somoene told me how can I update the Entity :

```
 public void VendreProduit(int idproduit, int idcentre)
    {
        var produit = db.Produits.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProduitId ==  idproduit);
        int qtn = produit.ProduitQuantite - 1;

        db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        Produit prod = new Produit();

        prod.ProduitQuantite = qtn;

        db.Produits.Attach(prod);
        db.Entry(prod).Property(p => p.ProduitQuantite).IsModified = true;
        db.SaveChanges();

        Vondu v = new Vondu();
        v.ProduitId = idproduit;
        v.CentreId = idcentre;
        v.VonduDate = DateTime.Now;

        db.Vondus.Add(v);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I want to update product quantity, I am using this method but it's not working and generates an exception.

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the Exception? What is the Exception?

Comment: you are asking for update but in your code you are trying to add a new entity.

Comment: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entities are tracked for changes by the DbContext.  There's no need to spin up a new product.

```
public void VendreProduit(int idproduit, int idcentre)
{
    var produit = db.Produits.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProduitId ==  idproduit);

    produit.ProduitQuantite -= 1;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```